# How do I delete my profile?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

How do I delete my profile so I don't exist on this website please?
I've tried everything I can think of but by signing in with my Google account in error thinking it was something else.

Comment: Please read https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 4):

To visualize Ruben's comment, please have a look at the image below.

[image: delete profile]